# How to install multiple Sitecore packages at once?

Tags: packages

The Sitecore Installation Wizard allows to install only one package. 
What is the best way to install multiple packages at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use Powershell (Sitecore Powershell Extensions).

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/install-package

> Install-Package [[-Path] ] [-InstallMode ] [-MergeMode ] [-DisableIndexing]

This will install a Sitecore package from the specified path.
You could add several of these statements into one powershell script if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can also unzip all the `package.zip`s and put it into one package. As @MichaelWest suggested you would also need to merge the `package.zip\installer\project` files. But be aware this way is the hacky way, you could have conflicts with files and items.

With this workaround you can use the Package Install Wizard if you don't want to/you are not allowed to use Sitecore Powershell Extensions because of any reason.

Comment: This would require the project file xml to be merged, right?

Comment: That's right @MichaelWest, exactly the `package.zip\installer\project` file.